# Android - TextView text is centered from its beginning letter

Tags: android, textview, center, gravity

I have this problem, using TextView : (below is the screenshot link)

http://nicolas-barroso.legtux.org/textview.png

I would like the text to be centered in TextView, and after some research, its appears to me that I seem to use the right code, but it doesn't work...

This is the xml code I use :

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/sad_button"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_menu"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Sad"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Help would be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Why you giving background and src both to ImageView?

Comment: did you try `layout_gravity` with/or `center_horizontal` on textview?

Comment: @PedroHawk Do you know diff. between them?

Comment: @PedroHawk, I guess layout_gravity works with the view, gravity should work with the inner text

Comment: For text size used sp instead dp in android

Comment: Your code is right and its working for me. Keep your LinearLayout width `fill_parent` or `match_parent`

Comment: Refresh Your view, May it is not refreshed after you changed.

Comment: @ツPratikButaniツ is right, code is working for me too

Comment: Your code is working fine, if it is not working for you try centering text from your program like: textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); or textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Comment: And Yaa... @Nicolas, You don't know android. `text` and `textSize` given in `ImageView` and `textSize` of `TextView` is given in `dp`

Comment: Thanks for response,

I did use layout_gravity with/or center_horizontal, but its the same result :(

@ツPratikButaniツ I cannot change my LinearLayout width, because its contained in parents view that compose all my Fragment view...

Comment: Have you tried changing it programmatically/dynamically? read my previous comment.

Comment: my point is to center the textview on layout. on that image i dont rly know if it is centered or not. about the text it is alligned to right, which is suspicious (since gravity is center). did you have any code setting your textview?

Comment: and yes, try removing this background, use only resource. You might be commiting some small mistake..

Comment: @PedroHawk the example is fair, the textview width fill its parent width, and all is in the xml file, no Java code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `gravity` on `LinearLayout` centered all childs. i remove `gravity` on `textview` and width and height `wrap_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sad_button"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_menu"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sad"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

hope this can help

Answer (score 1):

Use The Following line in TextView:

**android:gravity="center"**

& also use sp instead of dp